# Cannot get prebuilt LAPACK dll's to work in gfortran

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran, lapack, scientific-computing

Firstly, I am not a programmer by trade and have no formal experience or schooling in it.

For my Msc thesis I have to use LAPACK in order to solve a system of linear equations in fortran. I am not familiar with building LAPACK myself but found there are prebuild libraries which I can, [according to this thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1678628) use directly. I have downloaded the 32 bit and 64 bit dll's `liblapack.dll` [from here](https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries), and placed them in the same directory as my fortran code. I have renamed them `lapack32.dll` and `lapack64.dll` respectively - I am unsure how to check if I have 32 bits or a 64 bits compiler.

A test code `testinv.f90`, taken from the aforementioned forum thread is used to verify installation:

```
Program LinearEquations
    ! solving the matrix equation A*x=b using LAPACK
    Implicit none
  
    ! declarations
    double precision :: A(3,3), b(3)
    integer :: i, pivot(3), ok

    ! Say we are alive:
    print*, 'Hi this is working!'
    
    ! matrix A
    A(1,:)=(/3, 1, 3/)
    A(2,:)=(/1, 5, 9/)
    A(3,:)=(/2, 6, 5/)
    
    ! vector b
    b(:)=(/-1, 3, -3/)
  
    ! find the solution using the LAPACK routine DGESV
    call DGESV(3, 1, A, 3, pivot, b, 3, ok)
  
    ! print the solution x
    do i=1,3
      write(*,9) i, b(i)
    end do  
  
    9 format('x[', i1, ']= ', f5.2)  
  end program LinearEquations
```

The expected results of this program are that the line 'Hi, this is working!' and the solution (3 values) to the linear system are printed to the terminal.

Compilation was done using the following, for 32 and 64 bits:

*64 Bit:* `gfortran -o testinv testinv.f90 -L. lapack64.dll; ./testinv.exe`
Here the compiler spits out an error about not recognising `lapack64.dll`: `lapack64.dll: file not recognized: file format not recognized collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

*32 Bit:* `gfortran -o testinv testinv.f90 -L. lapack64.dll; ./testinv.exe`
This does actually compile and produce testinv.exe (size 49 kb), but running this, produces not a single result (nothing is printed to the terminal).

Is the way I am trying to get LAPACK to run from fortran a valid one? Or am I missing something? I appreciate any help and patience.

Comment: If it compiles and produces an executable, there's no reason that it prints nothing. If you compile without the lapack dll of comment out the call to `DGESV`, does it print something? What is your version of WIndows? How did you install gfortran? Which gfortran version is it?

Comment: Commenting out the call to `DGESV( )` does cause the expected result: the line 'Hi, this is working!', and the unsolved vector [b] are printed.

I am on Win11, and gfortran 9.2.0, installed using MinGW.

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions given on the link from where you have downloaded the library? Normally LAPACK requires BLAS. It seems that your migw is 32 bits...

Comment: I have difficulty understanding exactly what these mean, and they seem to be geared at using them using C/C++. In the first link, the replying author states that he used only liblapack.dll or liblapack.lib (I take it this is compiled vs uncompiled??) and the program ran just fine.

Comment: I can't help that much, I am not used with Windows/migw. If I had to use gfortran on Windows I would do through WSL.

Comment: A typical error with these DLL is missing dependencies: libgcc_s_seh_64-1.dll and libgfortran_64-3.dll must be provided by your MinGW installation (and visible in PATH). It's not always the case: for instance, with Rtools (MinGW for R), they aren't provided, so even though I can compile and link, I get an error at runtime: a message box for each missing DLL.

Comment: Instead of trying to find a matching MinGW, I suggest you install MSYS2, and from the package manager, install gcc, gfortran and blas/lapack. You can get MSYS2 here: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Note also that the post you quote is from 2012. AFAIK the most recent standalone distribution of MinGW-w64 is [from 2018](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/). Currently the preferred way to install MinGW seems to be MSYS2. You might also try [Octave](https://octave.org/), the Windows distribution comes with its own MSYS2, including gfortran, blas and lapack, and you also get a nice Matlab-like language.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, appreciate it. My supervisor explicitly told me to use MinGW, and not any other method of installing gfortran on my system. I have attempted to install gfortran using msys2, but had no luck (perhaps I will post another question on this - msys2 confuses the hell out of me).

Comment: If your supervisor makes a tool mandatory in the group/team, can't you get some help in the group/team?